# How do I choose the number of connection for load balancer?

Tags: load-balancing

I want to add hardware load balancer for apache and I want to know how many people are connected to my server to to choose the type of load balancer:

- Local Load Balancing with SSL - 250 Connections
- Local Load Balancing
  with SSL - 500 Connections
- Local Load Balancing with SSL - 1000 Connections

I run the following commands in the same time:

```
netstat -nt|grep -c :443 ( all connection wait and ESTABLISHED)
result : 1208

netstat -ant | grep 443 | grep EST | wc -l ( just ESTABLISHED connection)
result :106
```

My question:
Whichever is the correct value to choose the load balancer all connection or just ESTABLISHED ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably somewhere in between - but to be on the safe side, all of them.

However:

1) you've got a very large discrepancy between your established connections and others which you should be looking at - you're paying for a lot of hardware to spend most of its time in a confused state.

2) why use a hardware load balancer? Even if you're not bothered about server affinity, it makes a lot more sense to terminate the SSL on the outside device, and to cache HTTP there. Apache Traffic Server will handle this along with all the other things you'd want to do on a load balancer.